# How to loop through a SQL query and output individual emails base on

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfloop

I'm trying to loop over information from a query and send that information in an email. Currently, based on my stored procedure, I'm displaying all the rows in the email.

This is what I'm using to get the above information:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" id="left">Admin Name</th>
      <th scope="col" id="middle">Department Name</th>
      <th scope="col" id="right">Last Logon</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <cfloop query="#inactiveAdmins#">                
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">#Admin_Name#</td>
        <td class="text-left">#Dept_Name#</td>
        <td class="">#(Len(Last_Logon) ? dateFormat(Last_Logon, 'mmm dd, yyyy') : 'Never Logged On')#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is displaying all **Admin Names**, All **Department Name**s and all **Last Logon**.

I need to be able to loop over each department and send an email to each department individually.

To loop over each department, this is what I'm trying, but it's not returning any results. My question is:

**Is the syntax correct?**

```
<cfloop query="#ALEmail#">
  <cfquery dbtype="query" name="inactiveSW">
    SELECT Dept_ID
    FROM inactiveSW
    WHERE Dept_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#ALEmail.Dept_ID#">
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: The query attribute of the cfmail tag could simplify this for you.

Comment: On a personal note, any time I see a `cfquery` inside of a `cfloop`, I try to see if it can be done better. Every time you loop, you create a new database connection, and you can seriously slow down your application.

Comment: @Shawn - Isn't this why QoQ was created? I initialize that connection when I call my storedproc, and then create a QoQ from the recordset and query off that. I think that keeps everything moving smoothly, right?

Comment: I'm not a fan of QoQ if you don't need to use it. It's not really SQL, and isn't optimized as such. Plus it can easily trip you up, and may not necessarily be needed if the query gets the correct info in the first pass.

Comment: This appears to be one query that is looping around another QoQ. Is it possible to get that `Dept_ID` you need in the original query?  ie, if your `AllEmail` query has 100 rows, you'll be calling the `inactiveSW` QoQ 100 times to get a single field that you're already passing to the QoQ. You're asking to return the `Dept_ID` where the `Dept_ID` is "X". You already have the `Dept_ID` and don't need to query again for it.

Comment: If you are pulling other information out of `inactiveSW`, then I still believe you can combine that data into the original query. If the data is coming from two unconnected data sources, you could still programmatically join that data together without doing another query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it is long

should be

On this part

```
  <cfquery dbtype="query" name="inactiveSW">
    SELECT Dept_ID
    FROM inactiveSW
    WHERE Dept_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#ALEmail.Dept_ID#">
  </cfquery>
```

Because the `FROM` is the same as the `name=`, it is like to either have a syntax error, or overwrite an existing variable.

Besides, you are just selecting a variable that already exists. This doesn't get any new information. Are you trying to test for existence of dept_id?

---

Lastly, if you are trying to send an email based on a query, it is really straight forward

```
<cfmail
query="ALEmail"
from="#from#"
to="#to#"
subject="#subject#">


     Content here


</cfmail>
```

Comment: I suspect that your mail example will throw an error.  You would either have to change the cfoutput to cfloop, or add a group attribute to the mail tag.